# How to return rows that sum(field) <= value

Tags: mysql

The concept is to find the rows in which `sum(fCurrAmt)` may higher than the entered amount but should not lower than entered amount. I dont know how to explain indetail this creteria.

Lets say I have a table demo

Scenario : 1

```
id fCurrAmt price
------------------
1    1      10
2    1      20
3    2      25
4    3      30
```

If the entered amount is 3, I need to return first 3 rows

```
id fCurrAmt price
------------------
1    1      10
2    1      20
3    2      25
```

In the above scenario, sum(fCurrAmt) is 4 which is higher than entered amount.

Scenario : 2

```
id fCurrAmt price
------------------
1    1      10
2    1      20
```

If the entered amount is 3, I need to return there is no records.

In the above scenario, sum(fCurrAmt) is 2 which is lower than entered amount.

I have tried with below code in scenario 1

```
SELECT a.id,a.price,a.total,a.fCurrAmt from (
  select b.id,b.price,b.fCurrAmt,(
        select sum(fCurrAmt) from demo c where c.id <= b.id order by c.id
  ) as total from demo b
) a where a.total <= 3
```

It returns first 2 records only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This** You need to use `subquery` and `min` with `group by`. Using `subquery` we can return the minimum `id` where the `sum` is satisfied with given numbers and then join the `id` to retrieve full rows upto the id

```
SELECT * 
FROM test t
INNER JOIN(
        SELECT MIN(id) valId 
        FROM (
            SELECT t.id,
                    (SELECT SUM(t1.fCurrAmt) 
                    FROM test t1 
                    WHERE t1.id <= t.id) AS Rowsum
            FROM test t) t2 
         WHERE Rowsum >= 3) t1 ON t1.valId >= t.id;
```

**SQL Fiddle** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1d07/13

Comment: Hi Susang, your query best fits to me. I need one more help. I have made some additional code in the query you provided [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c59b7/1) . Can you tell me if it's correct & efficient ?

Comment: Not able to check `Query Execution Plan` in `SQL Fiddle` and MySQL is not installed in my PC so can you please check that with some more data ? and if possible avoid code duplication for `quantity`. I am not sure about the result, can just hope it's returning the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 DECLARE @sumOfFCurrAmt int
     DECLARE @sumOfEnteredAmt int

    set @sumOfFCurrAmt=(select Sum(fCurrAmt) from demoB)
    set @sumOfEnteredAmt=(select sum(fCurrAmt) from demoC)

    IF(@sumOfFCurrAmt>@sumOfEnteredAmt)
    BEGIN
    SELECT top(@sumOfEnteredAmt)* FROM demoB 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly lengthy way but it works.

First, I would store the sum of fCurrAmt up to the number entered in a temporary table. Hence, the first three statements are DROP, CREATE and INSERT. I would then take that value to check if the sum of those rows until the number entered are greater or lesser, if it is greater, then return all the rows until the threshold else return nothing. Here, sof12 is the same table as scenario 1 and sof14 is the same table as yours in scenario 2.

**SCENARIO 1:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tempsum`;

CREATE TABLE tempsum (`sum` integer(13));

INSERT INTO tempsum (SELECT SUM(fCurrAmt) FROM 
(SELECT NULL AS id, NULL AS fCurrAmt, NULL AS price, NULL AS total
FROM dual
WHERE (@total := 0)
UNION
SELECT id, fCurrAmt, price, @total := @total + fCurrAmt AS total
FROM sof12
WHERE @total <= 3) as new2);

SELECT id, fCurrAmt, price FROM (
SELECT NULL AS id, NULL AS fCurrAmt, NULL AS price, NULL AS total
FROM dual
WHERE (@total := 0)
UNION
SELECT id, fCurrAmt, price, @total := @total + fCurrAmt AS total
FROM sof12
WHERE @total <= 3) As new3 HAVING (SELECT SUM(SUM) FROM tempsum) >= 3;
```

Output of this case:

```
id   fCurrAmt   price
1      1         10
2      1         20
3      2         25
```

**SCENARIO 2:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tempsum`;

CREATE TABLE tempsum (`sum` integer(13));

INSERT INTO tempsum (SELECT SUM(fCurrAmt) FROM 
(SELECT NULL AS id, NULL AS fCurrAmt, NULL AS price, NULL AS total
FROM dual
WHERE (@total := 0)
UNION
SELECT id, fCurrAmt, price, @total := @total + fCurrAmt AS total
FROM sof14
WHERE @total <= 3) as new2);

SELECT id, fCurrAmt, price FROM (
SELECT NULL AS id, NULL AS fCurrAmt, NULL AS price, NULL AS total
FROM dual
WHERE (@total := 0)
UNION
SELECT id, fCurrAmt, price, @total := @total + fCurrAmt AS total
FROM sof14
WHERE @total <= 3) As new3 HAVING (SELECT SUM(SUM) FROM tempsum) >= 3;
```

Output of this case: No records returned.